# How to get header fields in a CORS request using Fetch api

Tags: javascript, http-headers, cors, fetch-api

I have a server of which the source code is inaccessible, so I don't know what it going on there.

I am trying to send a CORS request to it and the request is a success. The response should have a Location header and I can confirm that it is present using cURL as well as Firefox's Network Monitor tab in the Dev Tools. But I cannot access this in JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest or fetch api.

My code using fetch api is as follows.

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  body: 'creating a new session',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Location',
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
  },
}).
then((res) => {
  if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
    console.log('Location:', res.headers.get('Location'));
  } else {
    throw new Error('Ooops...something went wrong.');
  }
})
.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

In the Firefox's Network Monitor tab, I get the following entries.

```
[Response Headers]
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost:8081"
Content-Length: <some length>
Date: <some date>
Location: <required info is shown>
Server: <some info>

[Request Header]
Host: <host name>
User Agent: <user agent info for Firefox>
Accept: <a lot of stuff>
Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
Content-Type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
Referer: "http://localhost:8081"
Origin: <same as Referer>
Content-Length: "22"
Authorization: <some string>
Connection: "keep-alive"
```

What do I need to do to extract the Location header?

Comment: so, your status is 2xx? and `console.log('Location:', res.headers.get('Location'));` doesn't log anything?

Comment: @JaromandaX Status is 201 and it prints 'Location: null'.

Comment: do you see that `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Location` header isn't in the request headers - it would be in the preflight `OPTIONS` request, and to be honest, I think you're doing CORS wrong - you want to RECEIVE location, so why would you set Location as a Request-Header?

Comment: The **server** would need to response with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` for you to be able to access it

Comment: read what [Access-Control-Request-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) actually means. It's not a header **you** would ever set - the solution is as above, the **server** needs to grant access to the Location header it returns in the response

Comment: @JaromandaX
So instead of `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, should I specify something in my request header? 

Or, if the response has `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location`, then I should be able to access the Location header using `res.headers.get('Location')`?

Comment: `Or, if the response has` - yes, that one - you can safely remove setting `Access-Control-Request-Headers`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you. I will talk to the person who wrote the server and get him to support that. 

Just to confirm, if the server has set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` in the response header, then it should show up in the Firefox's Network Monitor, right? I only see the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers there.

Comment: Firefox developer tools show what is received - of course if another header is sent it will show up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as @JaromandaX pointed out, it was the lack of `'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Location'` in the server response which caused the Location header to be inaccessible from the response object. Had to fix it in the server and now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Perfect! A lot of other answers were talking about `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. It took me a while to figure out it needed to be `Access-Control-EXPOSE-Headers`